# oracle apex process limited rows at page load in Interactive Report

Tags: oracle, pagination, oracle-apex

I have Interactive Report with thousands of Records and Using functions inside the sql query. when the report loads it take too much time to process all rows around 10 mins. However i can't change any thing in query as it is already normalized and working fine.  i want that when IR load it should load rows as User Switch to Pages , For example At first load 50 rows are loaded rest of rows should wait until user press next Page. so query will be performing calculations only for 50 rows at each hit by user on page.

Comment: "... as it is already normalized and working fine". OK then. Check whether there's some sorting or grouping in the Interactive Report. If so, remove them and try again; see what happens.

Comment: only sorting are being used

Comment: That might cause problems. I'd say that you'd experience the same issue if you run query in SQL Developer (or SQL*Plus or TOAD or whichever tool you use), by adding the same ORDER BY clause. Database returns initial result set (the first 100, 200 or 500 rows) *fast*, but - if there's an ORDER BY clause, it has to fetch **all rows** in order to sort them. Anyway: from my point of view, it is useless to fetch "thousands of records" (as you said). Who will be scrolling through them? Set some filters first (as page items), then perform query so that it returns small record set. Fast.

Comment: i can remove the sorting , but is this possible to fetch only first 50 records but once user press next it should fetch next set of records

Comment: I wouldn't know, sorry.

Comment: @AdeelAslam, one option might be use a IG as object with appearance as IR, then in the IG object you can define PAGINATION instead of SCROLL. If you don't do the order by , the records will be presented unsorted per page

Comment: Also ensure pagination does not include "of Z"

Comment: What version of Oracle?  What version of APEX?  Currently, (at least Oracle 12.2 and APEX 5.1.4) APEX does do some "paging" where it only fetches X rows, where X is the number of rows selected in the IR options bar, typically 50.  But as other comments note, you may be doing something that requires the full data to be queried.